# Why application cookies is not being captured in HAProxy 2.1?

Tags: haproxy

Im upgrading from HAProxy 1.8 to 2.1 and the noticed that my application cookie that always start with _af (e.g. _afWMQB = hC6kMPel--6cYhNE) is not being captured by HAProxy causing HTTP 404 error.

What could

backend app1
balance roundrobin
timeout http-keep-alive 60s
cookie AFROUTEID insert indirect nocache
option httpchk GET /health
http-request replace-uri ^/app/(.*) /\1
server af01 app-01:12001 check cookie .App01 inter 5s fall 2 rise 1
server af02 app-02:12001 check cookie .App02 inter 5s fall 2 rise 1

in v1.8
we get 3 Set-Cookie in the response header,

Set-Cookie:
BFROUTEID=.App01; Path=/rcas; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:
JSESSIONID=65829ADC13BF2BEABDC65XXXX; Path=/rcas; HttpOnly; Secure

but now it is missing Set-Cookie that should have value
Set-Cookie: _afWMQB = hC6kMPel--6cYhNE

Anything Ive missed in the config file? Thanks!

I expect to have 3 set-cookies in the response header